# Recent Upgrade of PnP.Powershell and SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline Modules are causing errors

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp

I recently performed an upgrade of **PnP.Powershell** and **SharePointPnPPowershellOnline** Powershell modules due to an error I was getting. I had a few issues and tried a few things to resolve with no success. I then ran across Todd Kindtl's blog site and I ran the below commands to get the upgrades in.  https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=883
The previous error is now resolved but now I have new one below.

```
Uninstall-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Force –AllVersions
Uninstall-Module PnP.PowerShell -Force –AllVersions
Install-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Scope Allusers
Install-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell -Scope Allusers –AllowClobber
```

I'm get this error on another script that didn't have this issue before the upgrade.

*Connect-SPOService : The 'Connect-SPOService' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell'.*

Here is my output of get-module:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                
---------- -------    ----                                
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility       
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          
Manifest   1.2.0      PnP.PowerShell                      
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          
Binary     3.29.21... SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this error on the missing commandlet.

Does anyone know why I would be getting that error now?

Comment: Connect-SPOService is not a part of the PnP PowerShell module - rather the official MS PowerShell module for SharePoint Online just like the error states. To connect to a site using PnP, use ' Connect-PnPOnline'.

Comment: So I changed the 'connect-SPOService' to 'connect-PnPOnline' and I'm not getting this error:
`AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '31359c7f-bd7e-475c-86db-fdb' named 'PnP Management Shell'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.`

Any Suggestions? Has the Connect-SPOService been deprecated or is there a way to get it back?

Comment: The use of the "Connect-PnPOnline" cmdlet is a bit different with the new PnP PowerShell module.
You can find more information here: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/connecting.html
Hope this helps